# Missing classes for Attribute Routing in Web API 2.0: Two different System.Web.Http 5.0.0.0 dll's?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

Due to Web API 2's new features, I recently upgraded my MVC4 solution with Web API 1 to an MVC5 solution with Web Api 2. I followed [these official upgrading steps](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2) and got my solution up and running.

However, when I try to use new features, I notice there's something wrong with my System.Web.Http (referenced from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Stack 5\Packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.0.0\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll). If I compare my 5.0.0.0 System.Web.Http dll with a DLL in a working Web API 2 solution downloaded from the internet, classes like ContinuationResult, FormattedContentResult, HttpVerbAttribute, NonActionAttribute, 4 Override..-snip-..Attributes, RouteAttribute

Looks like all new Web API 2 features are missing, though I use the right reference. 
How is this possible?

Comment: Today I removed all my 4.5.x frameworks and Visual Studio 2013 to reinstall it. Sadly this didn't fixed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the Web Api 2.0 tutorial I was reading used a pre-release version of System.Web.HTTP. A silly search on the 'example-application-foldername' in Google brought me to [this article on asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/p/1922741/5549401.aspx?Re%20WebApi%20Attribute%20Routing)

The [changeset on codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets?size=100) learns me that the classes I was missing were removed after refactoring. [Some changes were made after the Release Candidate](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20MVC%20and%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs), in short: since v5.0 went in RTM you should use Attribute Routing like this:

```
[Route("actors/{actorId}/movies")] // Web API 2.0 Official release
```

Instead of this:

```
[HttpGet("actors/{actorId}/movies")] //Web API 2.0 prerelease
```